# AF Nikkor 50mm 1.8 stopped being recognized by D3500

Tags: nikon, 50mm

My lovely bride, of 40 years, bought me a new Nikon D3500 bundle. Loves me. I own a Nikkor AF d 50mm 1.8. Think it is about 13 years old. I have used it about 200 shots with the D3500 and worked great. Went to use it today and my D3500 says it is not recognized and the screen shows a blinking f_ _ _ in the aperture set area. The 50mm still works great on my D40. I reset my D3500 settings back to default. Any thoughts about what happened to my beautiful 50mm? I love it more than any other of my 8 lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Put D3500 back into Manual and it still shows no aperture setting because it is on the lens ring. Took picture. Dah. Always used D40 in Manual so did not have to set it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the original question. You can edit the question to add more information.

Comment: @EricShain disagreed. This does answer the question. The original asker answered their own question.

Comment: @scottbb Fair enough. I misunderstood it based on the rather casual syntax.

Comment: Alas, she was not to know that the D3500 had lost the feature of preceding D3x00 bodies that let them use AF and D lenses with auto exposure and control of aperture via command dial. Nikon is to be criticised for this intentional omission.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-mount your lens to the camera but before that, rotate the aperture ring back and forth a few times.